# pthread_cond_timedwait call is not working with mutex locking mechanism

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I have a logging application. In which after specific time (user configureable time) i need to close the current log file and and create a new log file and log the data.

There are 2 critical sections of code in my program.

1. Writing the data to file (in `while(1)`)
2. Close and open the new file

Whenever time expires i need to stop the logging to the file and close it & open the new log file and start logging.

For this purpose i have created a sample application exactly same as my application, but instead of file operation here am doing with `printf`.

I am using `pthread_cond_timedwait` call to handle the timer related operation. Here is my sample code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>

/* For safe condition variable usage, must use a boolean predicate and  */
/* a mutex with the condition.                                          */
pthread_cond_t      cond  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t     mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t     lock  = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
#define WAIT_TIME_SECONDS       10

void *threadfunc(void *parm)
{
    int               rc;
    struct timespec   abstime;
    struct timeval    now;

    /* Usually worker threads will loop on these operations */
    while (1) {
        rc =  gettimeofday(&now, NULL);

        /* Convert from timeval to timespec */
        abstime.tv_sec = now.tv_sec + WAIT_TIME_SECONDS;
        abstime.tv_nsec = (now.tv_usec + 1000UL * WAIT_TIME_SECONDS) * 1000UL;
        abstime.tv_sec += abstime.tv_nsec / (1000 * 1000 * 1000);
        abstime.tv_nsec %= (1000 * 1000 * 1000);

        printf("Thread blocked\n");
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        rc = pthread_cond_timedwait(&cond, &mutex, &abstime);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        printf("Wait timed out!\n");
        /* critical section of code */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        printf("Thread consumes work here\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int rc=0;
    pthread_t threadid;

    rc = pthread_create(&threadid, NULL, threadfunc, NULL);
    if (rc != 0) {
        printf("Thread creation failed err:%d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }
    while (1) {
        /* critical section of code */
        sleep(1);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        printf("One work item to give to a thread\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }

    printf("Wait for threads and cleanup\n");
    pthread_join(threadid, NULL);

    pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    printf("Main completed\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This code is not working. Whenever `pthread_cond_timedwait` expires `threadfunc` function should acquire mutex `lock` and it needs print the statements. After printing am releasing the mutex. But it is not happening. Control is never transfered from `main()` to `threadfunc`. Whats is going wrong here?

But instead of mutex if i use a variable to do the handling of critical section of code am able to do it. Say -

```
static int stop = 0; // take a global variable

//inside threadfunc
/* critical section of code */
stop = 1; //Replace pthread_mutex_lock with this 
printf("Thread consumes work here\n");
stop = 0; //Replace pthread_mutex_unlock with this 

//in main()
while (1) {
    /* critical section of code */
    sleep(1);
    if (!stop)
        printf("One work item to give to a thread\n");
}
```

This approach is working fine.

When i am using more then one mutex in my code am not able to implement this. What is the real thing happening behind? Am i missing anything while am using mutex to handle critical section of a code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Two things: 1) Don't lock `mutex` yourself, `pthread_cond_[timed]wait` already does so. 2) Why not use `sleep(3)`?

Comment: @a3f, NO!  `pthread_cond_[timed]wait` requires the specified mutex to already be locked by the calling thread.  It is then *unlocked* until the function returns.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Oh, you're right. @OP Still, why not use `sleep`?

Comment: @a3f. `sleep()` where to use it? I already mentioned if time expires i need to do the tasks. So in that case using `sleep()` inside critical section is allowed?

Comment: I suppose that @a3f is suggesting that you use `sleep()` instead of `pthread_cond_timedwait()`.  That would be more natural.  If you want a higher-precision timer then `select()` is a much more conventional choice than `pthread_cond_timedwait()`.

Comment: In any event, your code seems to work for me.  "One work item to give to a thread" messages are emitted at a rate of about 1 per second, and "Wait timed out!" / "Thread consumes work here" / "Thread blocked" messages are emitted at a rate of about one per ten seconds.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes. am also expecting that. Logically it should but with program its not working. I have tried it with my real code also. when am using another mutex am getting into this problem.

Comment: @Sathish, you misunderstand.  I'm not saying just that I *expect* your code to work, I'm saying that it *does* work.  I built it and ran it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It is working in my laptop. but not in my PC. In both am using ubuntu 14.04. Anyway thanks all.